# Solving two sets of coupled ODEs via matrix form in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

I want to solve a coupled system of ODEs in matrix form for two sets of variable (i.e. {y} and {m}) which has such a form:

> y'_n = ((m_n)**2) * y_n+(C * y)_n  ,   m'_n=-4*m_n*y_n

where `C` is a matrix, `[2 1, -1 3]`.

On the other hand I want to solve these equations:

> y'1= m1 ** 2 * y1 + 2 * y1 + y2
>    y'2= m2 ** 2 * y2 - y1 + 3 * y3
>    m'1= -4 * m1 * y1 ,
>   m'2= -4 * m2 * y2
>    y1(0)=y2(0)=-15. and m1(0)=m2(0)=0.01

to finally be able to plot ys and ms versus time via matrix form. I wrote the following program:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot,show
from scipy.integrate import odeint

C=np.array([[2,1],[-1,3]])
dt=0.001
def dy_dt(Y,time):
 y,m=Y
 m=m+dt*(-4.*m*y)
 dy=m**2*y+np.dot(C,y)
 return dy

m_init=np.ones(2)*0.01
y_init=np.ones(2)*-15.
time=np.linspace(0,4,1/dt)
y0=np.hstack((y_init, m_init))
y_tot=odeint(dy_dt,y0,time)



plot(time,y_tot[0])#y_1
plot(time,y_tot[1])#y_2
plot(time,y_tot[2])#m_1
plot(time,y_tot[3])#m_2
show()
```

but I encountered the following error:

```
 y,m=Y   
 ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Can anybody help me!

Comment: I have two sets of unknown parameters (here; {y1,y2} and {m1,m2}) that I want to solve and I think        odeint(dy_dt(y0,time)) is correct

Comment: `y,m=Y` this is the issue here. Do you know what unpacking is? in this line, both `y` and `m` have to take a value and the values are going to be supplied by `Y` which must therefore contain two, in other words be a container of 2 objects (integers, floats, containers, strings, something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`odeint` works with one-dimensional arrays.  In your function `dy_dt`, `Y` will be passed in as a one-dimensional numpy array with length 4.  To split it into `y` and `m`, you can write

```
y = Y[:2]
m = Y[2:]
```

The function `dy_dt` must also return a sequence of length 4, containing [y[0]', y[1]', m[0]', m[1]'] (i.e. the derivatives of the four quantities).  It looks like your function currently returns just two quantities in `dy`, so you will have to fix that, too.

This line

```
m=m+dt*(-4.*m*y)
```

looks suspiciously like Euler's method.  That's not what you want here.  Based on what you wrote in the question, you could write:

```
dm = -4. * m * y
```

Then you could return `np.hstack((dy, dm))`.

To summarize, you can write `dy_dt` like this:

```
def dy_dt(Y, time):
    y = Y[:2]
    m = Y[2:]
    dy = m**2 * y + np.dot(C, y)
    dm = -4 * m * y
    return np.hstack((dy, dm))  # or:  return [dy[0], dy[1], dm[0], dm[1]]
```

Comment: do you mean that I should change 'return dy' to 'return Y'?

Comment: No.  The function must return the time derivatives, i.e. the "right hand side" of the differential equations.  You already have four equations written down in the question; you called them `y'1`, `y'2`, `m'1` and `m'2`.  Once you have them computed, put them into sequence of length 4 (either a python list or a numpy array) and return the sequence.

Comment: I can not understand what you mean. This is a four line program, would you please write it? I encounter to an error when I change anything.

Comment: I put my suggested changes into a revised `dy_dt`.  That should get the code set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this to understand what is going on:

```
# we have a collection of different containers, namely list, tuple, set & dictionary
master = [[1, 2], (1, 2), {1, 2}, {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}]

for container in master:
    a, b = container  # python will automatically try to unpack the container to supply a & b with values
    print(a, b)  # all print: 1 2 since a = 1 and b = 2 after the unpacking
```

if i have a container with more values than the variables i am trying to supply, i get the "too many values to unpack" error, for example:

```
container = [1, 2, 3]
a, b = container  # this raises an error, the value 3 has nowhere to go
```

you can however say "dump all the rest to b" by:

```
a, *b = container 
print(a, b)  # -> 1 [2, 3] so a = 1 and b = [2, 3]
```

Back to you know, when you say: `y, m = Y` you have to make sure `Y` is a container with exactly 2 objects which does not seem to be the case. Lastly, as i said in the comments, you do not seem to call your function `dy_dt` anywhere.

Comment: if `Y` has two values `y, m = Y[0], Y[1]` and `y, m = Y` are (almost) the same thing and i dont understand what you mean by that second thing ("how can I ..")

Comment: `odeint(dy_dt(y0, time)) ` is *not* correct.  The way it is written in the question, `y_tot=odeint(dy_dt,y0,time)` is correct.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Do you need to pass a function to the `odeint()`? Thanks!

Comment: yes, dy_dt is just a name, because I used 'dy' in the function I just did not want to use dy as name of the function. You can change it to that name you want.

Comment: `scipy.integrate.odeint(func, y0, t,..)` i just checked the documentation. Sorry about that.